# pyenv fails with : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes' error

Tags: python

I have already seen https://bugs.python.org/issue34036 but it did not help.

I am trying to instal python using the followin command

```
 pyenv install 3.7.0
```

But it throws the following error

If the version you need is missing, try upgrading pyenv:

> Downloading Python-3.7.0.tar.xz...
>   -> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tar.xz Installing Python-3.7.0...
>
> BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 16.04 using python-build 20180424)
>
> Inspect or clean up the working tree at
>   /tmp/python-build.20181018113151.14218 Results logged to
>   /tmp/python-build.20181018113151.14218.log
>
> Last 10 log lines:   File
>   "/tmp/tmpecnjnct9/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/**init**.py",
>   line 42, in
>
> File
>   "/tmp/tmpecnjnct9/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py",
>   line 16, in
>
> File
>   "/tmp/tmpecnjnct9/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/index.py",
>   line 25, in
>
> File
>   "/tmp/tmpecnjnct9/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/download.py",
>   line 39, in
>
> File
>   "/tmp/tmpecnjnct9/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_internal/utils/glibc.py",
>   line 3, in
>
> File
>   "/tmp/python-build.20181018113151.14218/Python-3.7.0/Lib/ctypes/**init**.py",
>   line 7, in
>
> from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
>
> Makefile:1122: recipe for target 'install' failed
>
> make: *** [install] Error 1

Comment: For this and related issues, you'll find it best to first meet the general pyenv build prerequisites documented at https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems and note the troubleshooting instructions there.

Answer (score 38):

Install the `libffi` development package:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

and try again.

Comment: I have the same problem as OP, but do not have administrator rights, and cannot run `sudo` commands. What is the easiest solution in that case?

Comment: manually download the libffi-dev ubuntu package and extract the package, then define environment variable LIBRARY_PATH to point to the library folder which you just extracted and try to build