# Installing pylint without installing libffi-dev (No module named '_ctypes')

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, pylint

I want to install pylint, and I am getting the error `No module named '_ctypes'`. A solution described in [pyenv fails with : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52868280/pyenv-fails-with-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-ctypes-error) is to run `sudo apt-get install libffi-dev`. However, I do not have root priviledges, so cannot install `libffi-dev` on my machine. Is there any other way for it to work?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, pip 21.1.1 and python 3.8. Also, I am using `pyenv` for python

Answer (score -1):

The answer to the below issue solved it for me.

I'm also using pyenv and came across a similar issue with pyenv with it still not working even after installing `libffi-dev` (ubuntu 20.04) as per other SO questions on the topic - something to do with libffi being a higher version. Reinstalling with brew as per this answer did the trick for me.

```
$ brew remove --ignore-dependencies libffi
$ pyenv install 3.9.9
$ brew install libffi
```

Source: [pyenv building python on Linux Mint with WARNING: renaming "_ctypes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70004079/pyenv-building-python-on-linux-mint-with-warning-renaming-ctypes)

Comment: The OP explicitly notes, however, that he does not have root privileges. So I believe this will not work for his use case.